# stepping into typescript with browsers

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I maintain an administrative Web UI using a mixture of technologies due to legacy reasons, and I am slowing trying to migrate the code base to something more coherent. Typescript is on my radar as I am writing a lot of jquery and VueJS 2 code, and I am looking to get a better handle on it.

So I set up in vscode and I install typescript and @types/jquery and @types/axios and so on and so on. But starting to use them is not easy. The tutorials say to rename your .js to .ts and just go, so I pick one new file and do so. The dependencies of this code are normally pulled in by script statements in my html page and they pull right into the global namespace. No modules. But typescript needs them for static typing or I get compile errors.

So I add

import axios from 'axios';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

so now tsc is happy, but it generates code with an import in it, and the browser is not happy, complaining that import can only be used in modules. Not exactly a seamless drop-in, is it?

So if I want to slowly pull in typescript to enhance code quality, what can I do about the compiler insisting on generating code that my browser does not like? Why is this so difficult?

If I fake out the types in the import with "any" then I don't get strong typing, so why bother?

If I properly import Vue from 'vue' and use it like I have in the past with new Vue() I get a ton of errors signifying that I am using this type incorrectly now. So, I have to go and learn the Vue API all over again? Or am I missing something? This is not saving me time or increasing my code quality.

ie.

```
src/ts/siptrunks.ts:41:18 - error TS2339: Property 'init' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, (event: string, ...args: any[]) => Vue<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>, never, never, ...>>>'.

41             this.init();
```

This is because of my usual idiom:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#vue_trunks",
    data: {
        siptrunks: []
    },
    filters: {
    },
    created: function (this: typeof Vue) {
        this.init();
    },
```

Which is now broken? I keep hearing that all javascript is typescript so migration should be easy. This is not what I am finding.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The question is not very constructive. You're supposed to write type-friendly code in order for JS to TS transition to be seamless. And you need to be aware of TS in order to do this. There's no "init" on vue instance, so you can't expect `typeof Vue` to fix this. Use proper components instead of "new Vue" shortcuts, defineComponent exists to improve TS support. Use composition api because options api has natural limitations regarding TS

Comment: IOW completely rewrite my implementation from what was recommended in Vue 2.0 tutorials, so the transition will in no way be seamless. Got it.

Comment: Component-based code like https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript?#Annotating-Return-Types is preferably refactored to SFCs and translates reasonably well, notice "need annotation" parts which would be unnecessary with composition. As for legacy code with no demand for extensive rewriting, TS can add more problems than solve, nobody would argue that